# Why does Android require the package name to have at least two identifiers?

Tags: android

When creating a new Android application, [Eclipse](http://androidcodingtips.blogspot.com/2011/08/package-name-must-have-at-least-two.html) complains `Package name must have at least two identifiers` and [Netbeans](http://code.google.com/p/nbandroid/source/browse/project/src/org/netbeans/modules/android/project/ui/wizards/Bundle.properties?spec=svn46a5b01adf2736a4315e43c87b5b2eb75af2f58e&r=46a5b01adf2736a4315e43c87b5b2eb75af2f58e) complains `Package name must have at least two parts (Android Bug)`.

I understand how to work around this problem. My question is: where is this limitation coming from? I didn't find a mention of it in the Android documentation or the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues).

Comment: you understand how to work around this problem : **A sample package name can be something like com.google.haha**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is: where is this limitation coming from?

Particularly since the package must be unique on the device and unique on the Android Market, the strong recommendation is for you to use standard Java reverse-domain-name conventions for your package. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package):

> To avoid conflicts with other developers, you should use Internet domain ownership as the basis for your package names (in reverse). For example, applications published by Google start with com.google. You should also never use the com.example namespace when publishing your applications.

A domain name must have at least two segments; hence, the restriction requiring two segments.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to put at least two words separated by a dot.
For example:
daniel.bug

Comment: Your post doesn't actually answer the question.